# Why WCF service does not executing on IIS properly?

Tags: facebook, wcf, botframework

I've created WCF (IIS) service . That service should initialize conversation with users who have used talking to my bot.

The problem is : When someone is chatting, service executes on desired time. For all users.

But when nobody is writing to my bot, service does not executes.

It seems like when nobody chatting it sleeps :o

What do you think guys ? What's the reason ? Facebook, my WCF service or something else ?

Any idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say what's going on without more information, but notice that, by default, IIS will unload the worker process (W3WP) for your application pool after 20 minutes of inactivity. Might be what you're seeing.

You can disable this by setting the idle timeout property of the appPool to 0.

Comment: I set it up. I will write again later what happened ...  Thank you!

Comment: Same again. Service executes when some user writes to bot. 
Maybe you have another idea how to solve this ?

Comment: Again, we need more information. What do you mean by "does not execute"? What does facebook have to do with the thing?

Comment: Notifications should go on Facebook. Service initializes that. 
Notifications should appear every hour. But that's not happening. Users get notified one or two times per day .. .Does Facebook has some limit ? Or ?